# Ubuntu gives initramfs error and refuses to install

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-12.10

I have an Apple MacBook Pro 9,1 15 inch Mid 2012 non retina. I was trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. I used the information on this link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx to create a bootable USB. At the prompt, I selected the parameters `noapic`, `nolapic` and `nomodeset`. I selected these because I saw in a forum that to install Ubuntu on a Mac, enabling these parameters is recommended. And yes, the ISO file I used to Ubuntu is the 64-bit Mac (AMD64) desktop image found at http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/ and the file name is ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso. So, I clicked on `Install Ubuntu` and after some time where it showed Ubuntu 12.10 (and the 4 dots below were blinking), I was dumped into a terminal which said this

```
BusyBox v1.19.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.19.3-7ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) 
Enter ‘help’ for a list of built-in commands. 
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system.
```

And then it showed an initramfs prompt. I typed help and some list of commands came. I typed continue and it said something like unable to find /sb/init (I don’t remember exactly).

What do I do now? I absolutely need to install Ubuntu on my Mac.

I already have Windows 8 installed and presently it is a dual-boot setup but the partitions I manually created. Please tell me how to get out of this prompt as after that I can install Ubuntu from the standard GUI prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-downloaded the ISO file from the site and this time it installed. Probably the ISO file was corrupt then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 12.10 Live DVD.
Following hours of reading through forum posts related to the problem I re-downloaded the iso, and verified it's MD5 hash before re-burning the iso to a DVD (on lowest burning speed possible) - and still had the same output.

What solved the problem for me was [this answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2116659&p=12513241#post12513241).